# use many model class in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have that model class:

```
public class CV
{
 public PrivateInformation privateInformation { get; set; }
 public List<Education> education { get; set; }
 public List<WorkingExperience> workingExperience { get; set; }
}

public class PrivateInformation
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Education
{
public string UniversityName { get; set; }
public string Faculty { get; set; }
public string Specialization { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
public bool OnGoing { get; set; }
}

public class WorkingExperience
{
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
public string Position { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
public bool OnGoing { get; set; }
}
```

and there are another classes too. I want to make that user enter whole information from one page. (university can be more than 1 because I have list. working experience too).

But when I'm making CV as model class in view I can't access to `Education.Name`

How can I do that? Or is there any other way?

Comment: How are you accessing it? (`Education` is a collection so you need to use an indexer)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah I can't access. and can't get how can I do that because asked. I know my approach is bad

Comment: You have not shown your code! (SO is not a code writing service - its for helping your to correct errors with your code)

Answer (score 0):

The common pattern for doing that is creating a ViewModel class

Basically, create a class with all the properties you need for your view, and use it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx

Comment: Which is exactly what OP's `class CV` is!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a view Model of entire model and initilize properties of other classes in it if you want to use other propeerties also like,

```
Public class PrivateInformationViewModel
{

ublic string UniversityName { get; set; }
public string Faculty { get; set; }
public string Specialization { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
public bool OnGoing { get; set; }
public Education EModel {get; set;}

}
```

Now through this view model you can access education properties also.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with OP's question.

Comment: but what can I do if I want to use list of another class?